# Does js bracket notation for functions invokations work on all browsers

Tags: javascript

For example, given:

```
var object = {
  ["a function"]: function() {
     console.trace("that"); 
  }
}
```

Are there any browsers which are know to error when:

```
object["a function"]();
```

is invoked???

Comment: It's pretty standard.  I don't know how old your browser would have to be to not be aware of it.

Comment: Property access is completely quite unrelated to function call. Whatever is before the `()` is irrelevant as along as it resolves to a function. I doubt there is a browser that is not able to parse this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work in the object literal without any brackets on every browser.

```js
var object = {
    "a function": function() {
        document.write("that"); 
    }
}

object["a function"]();
```

Comment: Is this different than ES6 computed property names?

Comment: I'd be surprised though if there wasn't at least one version of IE where this doesn't work.

Comment: @Quantastical yes, but `a function` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks. I misread the question thinking `a function` was really `a()`.

Comment: *"It works [...] on every browser."* Do you have any sources to back up your claim? Not that doubt this is the case, but still...

Comment: @FelixKling, no, i change my answer.